# Combining VectorPlot and Graphics3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, replacement

I have a simple VectorPlot3D

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

Can I substitute the default arrows with Graphics3D object like:

```
Graphics3D[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {6, 2, 2}]]
```

?

Comment: Have you tried [`VectorMarkers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorMarkers.html)? You might be able to find a satisfactory built-in.

Comment: DId you instead want to use `VectorPlot3D` ?

Comment: @MarcoB yes, however none of the default options met my expectations

Comment: @Syed - the solution I am looking for it is whether there is a possibility to substitute the default markers with, for example, ellipsoid.

Comment: @ATomek The replacement process is easy: `VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}] /. Arrow[a_] :> yourNewGraphic[a]`. For instance, try `Line[a]` in that code. However, the problem with `Ellipsoid` is that it does not use coordinates the same way that `Arrow` does, so you will have to do some math to determine the appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option [`VectorStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorStyle.html) as follows:

```
VectorPlot3D[{z, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 VectorColorFunction -> Hue, 
 VectorPoints -> 3, 
 VectorStyle -> Graphics3D[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {6, 2, 2}]], 
 VectorScale -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.05]}, 
 ViewPoint -> {1.5, -2., 2.5}]
```

[image]

We can also use `VectorStyle -> {{None, Graphics3D[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {6, 2, 2}]]}}` to get the same picture. Using this form allows to assign different `Graphics3D` objects to the two ends of the arrows. For example,

```
VectorPlot3D[{z, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 VectorColorFunction -> Hue, 
 VectorPoints -> 3, 
 VectorStyle ->
   {{Graphics3D[Cuboid[-{1.5, 1.5, 1.5}, {1.5, 1.5, 1.5}]], 
    Graphics3D[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {6, 2, 2}]]}}, 
 VectorScale -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.05]}, 
 ViewPoint -> {1.5, -2., 2.5}]
```

[image]

We can override the automatic styling of arrowheads using desired directives inside `Graphics3D` (e.g., `Graphics3D[{desiredStyle, desired3Dprimitive}]`). For example, using

```
VectorStyle -> {{Graphics3D[{Green, Cuboid[-{1.5, 1.5, 1.5}, {1.5, 1.5, 1.5}]}], 
   Graphics3D[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {6, 2, 2}]]}}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: this works in version 11.3.0.